# How to make an integer enum declaration in java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My issue is the following:

i want to create an Entity  "grade" with an enum of an int (i use spring boot and hibernate to create the table of my DataBase) [image].
[image]
Can you help me please ?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5221149)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include any relevant code or textual information in your question as formatted text (see [mre]), not as links to pictures of text. Also, describe what difficulty you're having: ["Can you help me"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) is too vague.

Answer (score 4):

`enum` values must be *identifiers*, so you cannot do:

```
enum grade { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

You can do:

```
enum Grade { G1, G2, G3, G4 }
```

You can however make them print as 1, 2, 3, and 4:

```
enum Grade {
    G1(1), G2(2), G3(3), G4(4);

    private final int number;

    private Grade(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(this.number);
    }

    public static Grade of(int number) {
        return Stream.of(Grade.values())
                .filter(g -> g.getNumber() == number)
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid grade number: " + number));
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

To persist such an `enum` with JPA 2.1+, do as shown in [section 4](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-persisting-enums-in-jpa#converter) of article [**Persisting Enums in JPA | Baeldung**](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-persisting-enums-in-jpa).

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class GradeConverter implements AttributeConverter<Grade, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(Grade grade) {
        if (grade == null)
            return null;
        return grade.getNumber();
    }

    @Override
    public Grade convertToEntityAttribute(Integer number) {
        if (number == null)
            return null;
        return Grade.of(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was also going to post the same answer  +1

Comment: I want to connect my entity with a table of DataBase of my client (this is the table of my client: (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qdiDWxcui6xJG06WGGDZbfBI1dk59ZHv/view?usp=sharing).
in your way i have this table (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rPGeerHgu3SkU0M-Lq0f0ACXfPjQfNkG/view?usp=sharing).
thanks.

Comment: thanks man, in your way the type of Grade tin the table is an int but in the table of my client is an enum 
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qdiDWxcui6xJG06WGGDZbfBI1dk59ZHv/view)

Comment: @abchamcham JDBC doesn't do enums, so the JDBC driver probably handles enums as strings, so use `String` instead of `Integer`.

Comment: Hi Andreas,I finally find a solution:

    @Column(columnDefinition = "enum('hot','cold')")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @NotNull
    private HotCold temperature;

thank's for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the enum class and then compose the entity of a Grade. @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) will use the name of the enum element to store the object, i.e ONE, TWO, etc.

```java
public enum Grade {
    ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR
}
```

```java
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Grade grade;
```

Comment: I want to connect my entity with a table of DataBase of my client (this is the table of my client: (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qdiDWxcui6xJG06WGGDZbfBI1dk59ZHv/view?usp=sharing).
in your way i will not have this table 
thanks.